# Desktop background glitch after unlock Nvidia 1070 GPU

Tags: graphic-drivers, desktop, nvidia

After I unlock the computer, the desktop background becomes glitched like this. However everything still works. I am currently using the default background. I installed the Nvidia driver using this tutorial: [HowTo: Install latest NVIDIA Driver on Linux without getting black screen](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/howto-install-latest-nvidia-driver-on-linux-without-getting-black-screen.7/)

**Specs:**
Nvidia GTX 1070 (HDMI out to display),
i7 6800K,
32 GB DDR4 (2x 16 gb),
1x Crucial M4 512 gb(Elementary OS 0.4 Loki 64 bit),
1x Crucial M550 512 gb (Windows 10),
MSI X99 Gaming 7

[image: Desktop]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the exact same issue recently. I found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1620132) which mentions installing nvidia-370 from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa. After doing that I'm able to lock and unlock my desktop without screwing up the background - hopefully that helps in your case too!

Comment: I've been having the same issue (GTX 960M). I added the ppa, installed version 375, but just had the same glitches appear.